# Find numeric order of topological sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, topological-sort

I have acyclic graph with number label in each vertex I want to find [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) for this graph; however a graph may contain several topological order but I want to find specific order which vertex number have numerical order see picture below for more explanation 
[image]

As you can see in above picture this graph contain several topological order
4 5 6 1 2 3
1 4 2 5 6 3
1 2 4 5 3 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
......
But I  need this order `1 2 3 4 5 6` I want to know how should I change topological sort algorithm in order to find this specific order

Here is the another example :
[image]
In the example graph these two order is true
2 1 0
But when I use the first answer sort function it will swap 2 and 0 and final result will be `0 1 2` and this is a wrong answer

Comment: Did you test the answer i wrote ?

Comment: @Shasha99 yes but your answer doesn't work for all test cases

Comment: Could you please let me know a failed test case ? I ran on few without any issues.

Comment: I edit my question and add new example which your answer doesn't work on this example

Comment: If the comparison method returns false that means node1 is bigger than node2. Are you assuming the same ?

Comment: I have run the same for your second test case and it is giving expected output. You may check here:  https://code.hackerearth.com/9cc721w

Comment: Sorry I change my example to new one and this one dosen't work with your solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126766/discussion-between-shasha99-and-daniel-v).

Comment: Updated my answer and mentioned that only bubble sort can be used for sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better if you perform one more sorting on the output of your **topological sort algorithm** and use the following compare function while sorting:

```
//Suppose we have a method which returns true if an edge exists between two nodes.
//returns false otherwise.
edgeExists(node1,node2) ==true  // node1->node2

//The compare function
//consider node.value as vertex number.
bool compare(node1, node2){
    if(node1.value > node2.value && !edgeExists(node1,node2))
         return false;

    return true;
}
```

Below is an optimisation of compare method as suggested by @Gene:

```
bool compare(node1, node2){
      return (edgeExists(node1,node2) || node1.value < node2.value) ;
}
```

One very important thing to take into consideration is that this compare method will work correctly only if the vertices passed are consecutive in the topological order provided.

So we have to choose a sorting algorithm which always compares only the consecutive elements. Yes, The bubble sort !!!

Note that you can directly use the bubble sort to get the order but if you already have the output of the topological sort and want to get a more sorted ordering, you should use the above approach.

Comment: A minor improvement in if condition !!! Changed the order of expressions.

Comment: If you're doing a totally ordered sort anyway, then doing a preliminary topo sort is a waste. Just extend the partial order to a total one as you have done and use a standard system sort. @Daniel.V note! A more commonsense way to give the comparison is `return edge(a, b) || a.value <= b.value`. The meaning is "either honor the partial order if `a` and `b` are related by it, or choose the order with node labels."